# Trying to apply mod rewrite rule for e.g. css/style.123456.css -> css/style.min.css

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for any js/css files with a given time stamp to point to the real files but not really sure how to do it. Below is my attempt but when I try this it seems to mess up my

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(js|css)\/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.min.$4
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

By the way, my folder structure is as follows:

```
/public/
/public/index.php
/public/.htaccess (rules are written in this file)
/public/css/style.min.css
/public/js/all.min.js
```

Also, the apache vhost conf file will direct requests to the /public/ directory. This I can verify works. But when I try to view /css/style.12235543543.css (which I want to point to /css/style.min.css) it just goes through the front controller (index.php) instead of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^(js|css)/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.min.$4 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I can notice that when I remove the line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` it doesn't work. What is happening there? I don't really understand that part.

Comment: `RewriteCond` works only for the first `RewriteRule` just after. I changed the rule to not rewrite when the file or directory exists. this way, I can use one test for all rewrites after. 
And therefore `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means: for all (those who respect the above conditions) do nothing else.